# Smooth scrolling useRef for multiple sections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, smooth-scrolling

I want to smoothly scroll to the corresponding section using useRef scrollIntoView,
I am mapping an array of sections.

```
export function Sections({sections}) {
...
 <div className="w-full">
      {sections?.map((section) => (
        <Section
          key={section._key}
          section={section}
        />
      ))}
 </div>
```

SelectCarBrand is the component where I am clicking the buttons in,

```
export function SelectCarBrand({
  section,
}) {
  return (
    <section >
          {section?.map((button) => (
            <Button key={carBrand._id} button={button}  />
          ))}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Button component:

```
export function Button({button}) {
  const {title, logo} = button;
  return (
    <article className="flex w-1/3 justify-center">
      <button >
        {logo && (
          <Image
            className="fadeIn backface-hidden transition-transform duration-500 "
            width={440}
            objectFit="cover"
            alt={title}
            sizes={[]}
            layout="responsive"
            src={logo?.asset?._ref}
          />
        )}
      </button>
    </article>
  );
}
```

My goal is when clicking on a button of Button component, I want to be smoothly scrolled to it corresponding section in Sections component. How can I achieve this in React?

I tried the anchor tag, but I want to make it with useRef instead.